# subset a dataframe in Python with more than one query

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

What is the shortest way to subset a dataframe with multiple columns and find the number of rows that matches a query.

Is there an easier way to re-write the following piece of code.

The goal is to find the number of students who got the grades for all quarters and the ones who missed just the 4th quarter.

```
resDataFrame = df[(df['6th-Grade-Q1'] == 'Y') & (df['6th-Grade-Q2'] == 'Y' ) &  (df['6th-Grade-Q3'] == 'Y') & (df['6th-Grade-Q4'] == 'Y') ]
numberOfStudents = len(resDataFrame.index)
resDataFrame = df[ (df['6th-Grade-Q1'] == 'Y') & (df['6th-Grade-Q2'] == 'Y' ) &  (df['6th-Grade-Q3'] == 'Y') & (df['6th-Grade-Q4'] == 'X') ]
numberOfStudentsMissed = len(resDataFrame.index)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first line can be shorted tremendously, since the condition is always the same, and the column names follow a pattern:

```
df.filter(like='6th-Grade-Q').eq('Y').all(1).sum()
```

If there are other columns that begin with `'6th-Grade-Q'` than those 4, don't use filter and specify the 4 columns explicitly in a list. For the second condition you can use:

```
(df[['6th-Grade-Q1', '6th-Grade-Q2', '6th-Grade-Q3']].eq('Y').all(1) & df['6th-Grade-Q4'].eq('X')).sum()
```

Since you just want the counts there is no need to subset the original `DataFrame` and then calculate the length. Just sum the `True` values of the mask.

---

If you'd like a more general solution for checking many `&` operators between equality conditions across columns that don't follow a pattern then fall back to `numpy`. First specify a list of the column and equality you want to check as tuples:

```
import numpy as np
condlist = [('6th-Grade-Q1', 'Y'), ('6th-Grade-Q2', 'Y'),
            ('6th-Grade-Q3', 'Y'), ('6th-Grade-Q4', 'Y')]

np.logical_and.reduce([df[col].eq(val) for col,val in condlist]).sum()
```